# Is there any way to recover  a database after dropping from phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql-5, phpmyadmin, recovery

I was planning to drop all the tables from a test account, but unfortunately, I didn't notice that I was in the production account when I chose to drop all the tables of my db from phpmyadmin interface.

Is there any way of recovering my db content?

Comment: If you don't have a backup, not really.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, that you had such an accident.

If you have binary logs on, you could try the recovery options described here:
[Point in time recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html)

Another thing is to restore a backup, hopefully, you have one.
Changes made after this, could be restored as mentioned above.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a current backup restore from that backup.

If you don't you have just learned why you need to setup backups on your production servers.

Sorry.